# Oracle - Cycle detected while executing recursive 'WITH' query

Tags: database, oracle, recursion, cycle, recursive-query

I'm doing a basic example of recursive query with oracle sql. I'm computing future months of the format MON-YY. I managed to have a seemingly correct query but I don't understand the break condition with a WITH query.

I'm trying to break on the year value (for example stop when you reach 2020), but it detects a cycle while doing that. If I break on the month value (e.g. December), it works.

Here's my query with a month based break:

```
with
    prochains_mois(mois, annee) as (
        select 'sep' as mois, 19 as annee
        from dual
    union all
        select 
            case mois
                when 'jan' then 'fev'
                when 'fev' then 'mar'
                when 'mar' then 'avr'
                when 'avr' then 'mai'
                when 'mai' then 'jun'
                when 'jun' then 'jui'
                when 'jui' then 'aou'
                when 'aou' then 'sep'
                when 'sep' then 'oct'
                when 'oct' then 'nov'
                when 'nov' then 'dec'
                when 'dec' then 'jan'
            end,
            case mois
                when 'dec' then annee + 1
                else annee
            end
        from prochains_mois r
        where mois <> 'dec'
    )
select * from prochains_mois;
```

If I do this, it returns a consistent result.

```
MOI      ANNEE
--- ----------
sep         19
oct         19
nov         19
dec         19
```

Now if I try to break the recursive query on the year, let's say 2020, so I change the where condition in the with clause to :

```
where annee < 20
```

Then I get :

```
ORA-32044: cycle detected while executing recursive WITH query
```

I tried to break with a later month to see if my year addition works correctly, it seems to be the case. If I break on march, I get the January and February correctly :

```
where mois <> 'mar'
```

gives

```
MOI      ANNEE
--- ----------
sep         19
oct         19
nov         19
dec         19
jan         20
fev         20
mar         20
```

Comment: What version of Oracle is this running on?

Comment: Have a look at IS CYCLE clause. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABCDJDB). Or read [Tim Hall's article on Oracle-Base](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2#cyclic); it's usually a gentler read than the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DATE`s:

```sql
with prochains_mois( value ) as (
  select DATE '2019-09-01' from dual
union all
  select ADD_MONTHS( value, 1 )
  FROM   prochains_mois
  WHERE  value < DATE '2020-12-01'
)
select SUBSTR( TO_CHAR( value, 'mon', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=FRENCH' ), 1, 3 ) AS mois,
       TO_CHAR( value, 'RR' ) AS annee
from   prochains_mois;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> MOIS | ANNEE
> :--- | :----
> sep  | 19   
> oct  | 19   
> nov  | 19   
> dec  | 19   
> jan  | 20   
> fev  | 20   
> mar  | 20   
> avr  | 20   
> mai  | 20   
> jui  | 20   
> jui  | 20   
> aou  | 20   
> sep  | 20   
> oct  | 20   
> nov  | 20   
> dec  | 20
> ```

or use your query and check that the month **and** year do not match:

```sql
with
    prochains_mois(mois, annee) as (
        select 'sep' as mois, 19 as annee
        from dual
    union all
        select 
            case mois
                when 'jan' then 'fev'
                when 'fev' then 'mar'
                when 'mar' then 'avr'
                when 'avr' then 'mai'
                when 'mai' then 'jun'
                when 'jun' then 'jui'
                when 'jui' then 'aou'
                when 'aou' then 'sep'
                when 'sep' then 'oct'
                when 'oct' then 'nov'
                when 'nov' then 'dec'
                when 'dec' then 'jan'
            end,
            case mois
                when 'dec' then annee + 1
                else annee
            end
        from prochains_mois r
        where ( mois, annee ) NOT IN ( ( 'dec', 20 ) )
    )
select * from prochains_mois;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> MOIS | ANNEE
> :--- | ----:
> sep  |    19
> oct  |    19
> nov  |    19
> dec  |    19
> jan  |    20
> fev  |    20
> mar  |    20
> avr  |    20
> mai  |    20
> jun  |    20
> jui  |    20
> aou  |    20
> sep  |    20
> oct  |    20
> nov  |    20
> dec  |    20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b097f06c8a7f63e696009a343fc6dd68)*

Comment: So from what I understood, oracle thinks there is a potential infinite cycle because I break on year and year appears 2 times with the same value, but the pair (month, year) is unique each time, so it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: @Pythalex yes. If you don't want to use `NOT IN` then you could use `WHERE mois  != 'dec' OR annee != 20` but whichever you use you need to have both columns in the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you're trying to manipulate dates using strings/numbers. Don't do that; if you're working with dates, use dates!

E.g. you can do what you're after like so:

```
WITH prochains_mois (mnth_dt) AS (SELECT TRUNC(sysdate, 'mm') mnth_dt
                                  FROM   dual
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT add_months(mnth_dt, 1) mnth_dt
                                  FROM   prochains_mois
                                  WHERE add_months(mnth_dt, 1) < add_months(TRUNC(sysdate, 'yyyy'), 12))
SELECT mnth_dt,
       to_char(mnth_dt, 'mon') mois,
       to_char(mnth_dt, 'yy') annee
FROM   prochains_mois;

MNTH_DT     MOIS ANNEE
----------- ---- -----
01/09/2019  sep  19
01/10/2019  oct  19
01/11/2019  nov  19
01/12/2019  dec  19
```

N.B. You could simplify the predicate in the recursive sub-factored query to `mnth_dt < add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'yyyy'), 11)`.

This works by taking the start date (here, I've used `sysdate`) and finding the first of the month (by using the optional second parameter of `TRUNC` to specify the level we're truncating it to).

Then we simply add a month to each date until we hit the last month of the start date's year.

Only after you've got the dates do you then output the data in the format you require using `to_char`.